# JApplet crashing because of a for loop for an Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, japplet

this is my first post so go easy on me.
I'm doing some uni work and im not asking for any help or advice for the whole project.
Basically the whole thing does work kinda when i comment out a for loop:

```
          for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
          {
          textArea.append(words[i] + "\n");
          }
```

this is designed to work its way through an array but NetBeans keeps telling me to change it into an enhanced for loop but when i do it crashes. The whole program is designed to take an input from a `JAplet` interface, send it to `stringAnalyser` in a separate java file, record the length of words and how often words of that length occur, then send them back to the interface and print them onscreen in the centre console.

Here are both files i'm using if it helps:

```
package Assignment2;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class GUIAssign extends JApplet 
    {
    private JPanel pnorth,psouth,pcentre,pwest,peast;
    private JButton btnEnter,btnReset,btnSave,btnLoad;
    private JTextField txtEnter;
    private JLabel label1,label2,header;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private Container c;
    private paintPanel panelpaint;
    private String inputString,shape;
    private int x,y,size;
    private stringAnalyser tim;
        @Override
        public void init()
        {
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(800,600);
    initComponents();
    initPanels();
    initButtons();
    initText();
    initLabels();
    tim=new stringAnalyser();

        }
public void initComponents()
{
x=0;
y=0;
size=0;
this.panelpaint=new paintPanel();
}
public void initPanels()
{
 pnorth= new JPanel();
 pnorth.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
 this.psouth = new JPanel();
 psouth.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
 this.peast =new JPanel();
 peast.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
 this.pwest = new JPanel();
 pwest.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
 this.pcentre = new JPanel();
 pcentre.setBackground(Color.yellow);

}
String words[];
 public void initButtons()
{

  this.btnEnter=new JButton("Enter");
 btnEnter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        inputString=txtEnter.getText();
          tim.setText(inputString);
          words=tim.sendBack();

          for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
          {
          textArea.append(words[i] + "\n");
          }
          tim.output();


      }
  });


 this.btnReset=new JButton("Reset");
  btnReset.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          txtEnter.setText("");
          }

  });


  this.btnSave=new JButton("Save");
  this.btnLoad=new JButton("Load");
}
 public void initText()
 {
   txtEnter=new JTextField();
   textArea=new JTextArea();


         }
         public void initLabels()
         {
     this.label1=new JLabel("");
     this.label2=new JLabel("");
         }

       //structure
          @Override
       public void start()
       {
           panelEast();
           panelWest();
           panelNorth();
           panelSouth();
           panelCentre();
         c=this.getContentPane();
        c.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
         c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         c.add(pnorth,BorderLayout.NORTH);
         c.add(peast,BorderLayout.EAST);
         c.add(psouth,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         c.add(pwest,BorderLayout.WEST);
         c.add(pcentre,BorderLayout.CENTER);

       }

public void panelNorth()
{
    Font f=new Font("Jokerman",Font.BOLD,16);
   pnorth.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
   pnorth.add(new JLabel("           "));
    pnorth.add(new JLabel("Tim's String Lenght Tester"));
    pnorth.add(new JLabel("           "));

}
public void panelWest()
{
  pwest.add(new JLabel("                "));
   //pwest.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("src/tim.jpg")));
}
 public void panelEast()
{
  peast.add(new JLabel("                "));
}
public void panelSouth()
{
    psouth.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel psouth1=new JPanel();
    JPanel psouth2=new JPanel();


    psouth1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
    psouth1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    psouth1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED,Color.cyan, Color.black, Color.black, Color.cyan));
    psouth1.add(this.txtEnter);
    psouth1.add(this.btnEnter);
    psouth1.add(this.btnReset);


    psouth2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    psouth2.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    psouth2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED,Color.cyan, Color.black, Color.black, Color.cyan));

    psouth2.add(this.btnSave);
    psouth2.add(this.btnLoad);





    psouth.add(psouth1);
     psouth.add(psouth2);
}
public void panelCentre()
{

    pcentre.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    JPanel pcentre1=new JPanel();
    pcentre.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    pcentre.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED,Color.green,Color.green));
    pcentre.add(textArea);
    textArea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
    pcentre.add(pcentre1);


        }


         @Override
        public void setName(String n) {
            this.inputString=n;

        }

            public String getNameString() {
           return inputString;
        }


    @Override
       public void stop(){}
    @Override
       public void destroy(){}
    @Override
       public void paint(Graphics g){

       }




    }//close project`
```

file 2, this is the analysing java file:

```
    package Assignment2;


    public class stringAnalyser{
       //static String inputArray[]= {"Tim","John","Craig", "Andrew", "Bob", "Tom",                          "Phillipa","Billie-Bob"};
       private String inputString = "";

       private String removedCharString;//will store the string with removed chars
       private String array3="",array4="", array5="", array6="", array7="", array8="",         array9="", array10="",array11="",
               array12="",array13="",array14="",array15=""; 
       private String[] sendString;
       private int count=0;
    //will add the words with the appropriate length to a string for printing

   public void setText(String input)
   {
       this.inputString=input;
   }
  public String showme()
  {
      return "Think is not difficult believe is the word and look at me I am the great evidence!!!";

  }


public  void output()
{
int three=0, four=0, five=0, six=0, seven=0, eight=0, nine=0, ten=0,eleven=0,twelve=0,thirt=0,fort=0,fift=0;
// these ints will count how many times the words relevent length have accoured in a string
   String w[];
   removedCharString = inputString.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]", "");//remove chars
   w=removedCharString.split(" ");
   this.sendString=new String[w.length];

   for (String retval: removedCharString.split(" "))//split at any spaces
  {

   if (retval.length()==3){
       three++;
       array3 = array3 + retval + ", ";

     }//if 3
    if (retval.length()==4){
        four++;
       array4 = array4 + retval + ", "; 
     }//if 4
     if (retval.length()==5){
         five++;
       array5 = array5 + retval + ", "; 
     }//if 5
      if (retval.length()==6){
          six++;
       array6 = array6 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 6
      if (retval.length()==7){
          seven++;
       array7 = array7 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 7
      if (retval.length()==8){
          eight++;
       array8 = array8 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 8
      if (retval.length()==9){
          nine++;
       array9 = array9 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 9
      if (retval.length()==10){
          ten++;
       array10 = array10 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 10
      if (retval.length()==11){
          eleven++;
       array11 = array11 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 10

      if (retval.length()==12){
          twelve++;
       array12 = array12 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 10

      if (retval.length()==13){
          thirt++;
       array13 = array13 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 10

      if (retval.length()==14){
          fort++;
       array14 = array14 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 10

      if (retval.length()==15){
          fift++;
       array15 = array15 + retval + ", ";              
     }//if 10




  }//for string retval




    // print the results
   System.out.println(inputString);
   if (three!=0){
       count++;
       sendString[count]="There are: "+three+" three letter word/s; "+array3;
    System.out.println("There are: "+three+" three letter word/s; "+array3);}
   if (four!=0){
       count++;
       sendString[count]="There are: "+four+" four letter word/s; "+array4;
    System.out.println("There are: "+four+" four letter word/s; "+array4);}
   if (five!=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+five+" five letter word/s; "+array5);}
   if (six !=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+six+" six letter word/s; "+array6);}
   if (seven !=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+seven+" seven letter word/s; "+array7);}
   if (eight!=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+eight+" eigth letter word/s; "+array8);}
   if (nine!=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+nine+" nine letter word/s; "+array9);}
   if (ten!=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+ten+" ten letter word/s;"+array10);}
    if (eleven!=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+eleven+" eleven letter word/s;"+array11);}
     if (twelve!=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+twelve+" twelve letter word/s;"+array12);}
      if (thirt!=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+thirt+" thirteen letter word/s;"+array13);}
       if (fort!=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+fort+" forteen letter word/s;"+array14);}
        if (fift!=0){
    System.out.println("There are: "+fift+" fifteen letter word/s;"+array15);}

        }//output
      public String[] sendBack()
      {
          return this.sendString;
      }
        public static void main(String []args)
        {
            stringAnalyser a=new stringAnalyser();
            a.output(); 

        }//close main


    }//class`
```

thank you in advance for any and all input.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please only post relevant code (if we need more, we will ask).  Also, please post what line crashes, and the error type.

Comment: _"NetBeans keeps telling me to change it into an enhanced for loop but when i do it crashes"_ - It's just a suggestion. You don't _have_ to do it.

Comment: Also define _"crashes"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in `btnEnter.addActionListener` you only invoke `tim.setText(inputString);` which sets the input. But you never call `output()` or any other required methods on the analyzer that supposed to process the input. As a result, `tim.sendBack()` returns `null`. `stringAnalyser.sendString` is initialized only inside `output()`. Until then it remains `null`. So `words.length` triggers `NullPointerException` because `words` array is `null`.

The indentation and naming of the posted code is bit hard to follow at times. See Java [Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) section in particular. Most tools can auto indent the code for you, ie <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, sorry for the long wait in a reply. This project did get completed and it seems i had a large misunderstanding with what i was trying to achieve and the way i had tried to implement it.

Thanks again for your help and the the handy ctrl+shift+f shortcut.

Tim.